# Flatten an interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a usecase where I want to be able to derive the keys/fields of my type based on generic type.

For example:

These are the container interface

```
export interface IUser {
    id: BigInt;
    name: string;
    balance: number;
    address: Address;
}
export interface Address {
    street: string;
    city: string;
    zipcode: number;
    tags: string[];
}
```

I want to be able to define type that does something like

```
const matcher: Matcher<IUser> = {
  id: 1
}
```

this is something I could do using the Matcher implemented as below

```
export type Matcher<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: (number | string | boolean)
}
```

However now for the usecase like

```
const deepMatcher: Matcher<IUser> = {
  id: 1,
  user.address.city: 'San Francisco'
}
```

How can I update my model (Matcher) to support this use-case?

Comment: how can the `Matcher` type know, that a path could start with `"user."`? where does the information about the string `"user"` come from?

Comment: ` user.address.city: 'San Francisco'` this is by the way an error

Comment: @Tobias - I am trying to figure out what can be the best term in place of `user.` that I can fit in Typescript here? along with main question. Can I use `IUser.address.city` ?

Comment: no, unless you explicitly specify it like `Matcher<IUser, 'IUser'>`

Comment: @TobiasS. Matcher accepts a generic parameter T; OP essentially wants `Partial<{ [K in DeepKeys<IUser>]: DeepGet<IUser, K> }>`.

Comment: I am not familiar with Typescript much. I am ok to accept whatever key naturally fits the best in for Typescript developers.

Comment: would [this](https://tsplay.dev/w1yZOw) fit your needs? I am pretty sure this is a duplicate, but I could not find a dupe target yet.

Comment: @TobiasS. Thank you. Is it possible to replace `"address"` with `address` in your example?

Comment: yes, you can just remove the quotes and it still works fine

Comment: great thank you. I verified it works great. Could you please post it as answer with explanation. I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer: These types of problems always have a lot of edge cases. This solution works with your example but might break when we introduce  things like optional properties or unions. This solution will also not include paths of objects inside of arrays.**

The solution consists of two major parts:

First we need a type which will take a type `T` and constructs a union of all paths of `T`.

```
type AllPaths<T, P extends string = ""> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object 
      ? T[K] extends any[] 
        ? `${P}${K & string}` 
        : AllPaths<T[K], `${P}${K & string}.`> extends infer O 
          ? `${O & string}` | `${P}${K & string}`
          : never 
        : `${P}${K & string}`
}[keyof T]
```

`AllPaths` is a recursive type. The progress of each path gets stored in `P`.

It maps over all properties of `T` and does some checks. If `T[K]` is an array or not an object, it simply appends `K` to the current path and returns it.

```
T[K] extends object 
  ? T[K] extends any[] 
    ? `${P}${K & string}` 
    : /* ... */
  : `${P}${K & string}`
```

If `T[K]` is an object, we can recursively call `AllPaths` with `T[K]` as the new `T` and the current path with the current key again. This time we also append a `"."` to the path since we know that a nested property will be appended later.

```
AllPaths<T[K], `${P}${K & string}.`> extends infer O 
  ? `${O & string}` | `${P}${K & string}`
  : never
```

The `infer O` stuff here is a workaround so TypeScript does not complain with `Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite`. We return both the result of the recursive call and the current path here, so we can have `address` and also `address.street` ... as keys later.

Let's see the result here:

```
type T0 = AllPaths<IUser>
// type T0 = "id" | "name" | "balance" | "address" | "address.street" | "address.city" | "address.zipcode" | "address.tags"
```

---

We now need a type which takes a path and fetches us the correct type for the path.

```
type PathToType<T, P extends string> = P extends keyof T
  ? T[P]
  : P extends `${infer L}.${infer R}` 
    ? L extends keyof T
      ? PathToType<T[L], R>
      : never
    : never 

type T0 = PathToType<IUser, "address.street">
// type T0 = string
```

This is a recursive type too. `P` starts as a whole path this time.

We first check if `P` is a `keyof T`. If it is, we can return the type of `T[P]`. If not, we try to split `P` into the two literal types `L` and `R` which must be divided by a dot. If the left string literal matches a key of `T`, we can recursively call `PathToType` with `T[L]` and the rest of the path.

---

In the end we use both types inside the `Matcher` type.

```
type Matcher<T> = Partial<{
    [K in AllPaths<T>]: PathToType<T, K & string>
}>
```

We allow any string in `AllPaths<T>` as a key and fetch the corresponding type of the path with `PathToType<T, K & string>`.

The result looks like this:

```
type T0 = Matcher<IUser>
// type T0 = {
//    id?: number | undefined;
//    name?: string | undefined;
//    balance?: number | undefined;
//    address?: Address | undefined;
//    "address.street"?: string | undefined;
//    "address.city"?: string | undefined;
//    "address.zipcode"?: number | undefined;
//    "address.tags"?: string[] | undefined;
//}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFFMA8AcHsCcAuACAlgO0eeAzAhgMbjICSAqgM7bIDeoyDaAJgFzLoCuAtgEbYDc9RujxdwbCongYA5oJCNkPPABs86Im068BQhniZN44ChTYBBQ8dPyAvhBgIUGLLkLFLRkxVp7kk43BECSlZeUUCVEQATxDpdDk-AC9UaAJYJnF2bj54cMZEPBkzf1CEgG0AXTtQUBjoDxUVAAU8RAALCgAeABUAGmRm5CgsdCYfANlkAF5kACI5gD4Z3xAASHKAaTR0ZABrcGjYHGQeyrYercrhyFHx5FgeACtwAhRQNYYAflOrm7ufOpolVkB9FD8AAYAEhozVsMO2ADJSvEZLYIaD1msLE1Wh1updNpUBtDYfCaEiUbJbAA6CHLEbgMY+DA4agAeUxa0+yEhMM5yMmCXRyAAPshSXCEchBWU0RCPjytOAAG7URVsSXkylC+WgWzlA5HE5nWogerEPHtHqwHrRBq9AZDRnMqkJZazZ23Jn3I3HU5CH6XZqVIRsL0AiUw1nUAAytOj6DZ8GQACURX4frH-j6fH6TWDeYM2tbbfbwL1yrHiWnFoXlWr4B8G+qwOby8gALJtAjtbC9D3FpCoVRdOjrLY7ZDmXElgmLc7Fjo2u0O-rIHVyusgWzb0DpdCSZCZcDQbuIXvYNjny-wLrkKjwQfjhioVjIACMfSEcwMXlMNKFMUcxsOUv48AQczEkIf7WCU448pEMRsOBkHfusDABOAQQoXgEFzOhPIpGkGRZB+ABMADMhEMEBJRgXhkGhgoyD2DuZoWqcAAMKw3n2d4PtgixAA)

Comment: sure, just add `Partial` inside the Matcher type: https://tsplay.dev/WoGOMW